# Razor Pages .NET Core 2.1 Integration Testing post authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

I am looking for some guidance...

I'm currently looking at trying to write some integration tests for a Razor Pages app in .net core 2.1, the pages I'm wanting to test are post authentication but I'm not sure about the best way of approaching it. The docs seem to suggest creating a CustomWebApplicationFactory, but apart from that I've got a little bit lost as how I can fake/mock an authenticated user/request, using basic cookie based authentication.

I've seen that there is an open [GitHub issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1) against the Microsoft docs (here is the actual [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6882)), there was a mentioned solution using IdentityServer4 but I’m just looking how to do this just using cookie based authentication.

Has anyone got any guidance they may be able to suggest?

Thanks in advance

My Code so far is:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseMySql(connectionString);
                options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            });

            services.AddLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddSeq();
            });

            services.ConfigureAuthentication();
            services.ConfigureRouting();
    }
}
```

**ConfigureAuthentication.cs**

```
  namespace MyCarparks.Configuration.Startup
  {
      public static partial class ConfigurationExtensions
      {
          public static IServiceCollection ConfigureAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services)
          {
              services.AddIdentity<MyCarparksUser, IdentityRole>(cfg =>
              {
                  //cfg.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
              })
              .AddDefaultUI()
              .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

              services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
              {
                  options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
                  options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
                  options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
              });

              services.AddMvc()
                  .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                  .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
              {
                    options.AllowAreas = true;
                    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
                    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");

                    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Sites");
                });

            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

***Integration Tests***

**PageTests.cs**

```
namespace MyCarparks.Web.IntegrationTests
{
    public class PageTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory;

        public PageTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> webApplicationFactory)
        {
            factory = webApplicationFactory;
        }


    [Fact]
    public async Task SitesReturnsSuccessAndCorrectContentTypeAndSummary()
    {
        var siteId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var site = new Site { Id = siteId, Address = "Test site address" };
        var mockSite = new Mock<ISitesRepository>();
        mockSite.Setup(s => s.GetSiteById(It.IsAny<Guid>())).ReturnsAsync(site);

        // Arrange
        var client = factory.CreateClient();

        // Act
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:44318/sites/sitedetails?siteId=" + siteId);

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString()
            .Should().Be("text/html; charset=utf-8");

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        responseString.Should().Contain("Site Details - MyCarparks");
    }

    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As part of your test setup, use the test client to make a post to your login page with the credentials of the user you're testing against. Grab the auth cookie from the response and then send it back with the request to the actual page you're wanting to test.

Comment: Ok, got something working with your suggestion. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

For implement your requirement, you could try code below which creates the client with the authentication cookies.

```
    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> where TEntryPoint : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {

        });
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
    }
    public new HttpClient CreateClient()
    {
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        var uri = new Uri("https://localhost:44344/Identity/Account/Login");
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = cookieContainer
        };
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        var verificationToken = GetVerificationToken(httpClient, "https://localhost:44344/Identity/Account/Login");
        var contentToSend = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Email", "test@outlook.com"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", "1qaz@WSX"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("__RequestVerificationToken", verificationToken),
                        });
        var response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:44344/Identity/Account/Login", contentToSend).Result;
        var cookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("https://localhost:44344/Identity/Account/Login"));
        cookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        return client;
    }
    private string GetVerificationToken(HttpClient client, string url)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        var verificationToken =response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        if (verificationToken != null && verificationToken.Length > 0)
        {
            verificationToken = verificationToken.Substring(verificationToken.IndexOf("__RequestVerificationToken"));
            verificationToken = verificationToken.Substring(verificationToken.IndexOf("value=\"") + 7);
            verificationToken = verificationToken.Substring(0, verificationToken.IndexOf("\""));
        }
        return verificationToken;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Chris Pratt suggestion, but for Razor Pages .NET Core 3.1 I use a previous request to authenticate against login endpoint (which is also another razor page), and grab the cookie from the response. Then I add the same cookie as part of the http request, and voila, it's an authenticated request.

This is a piece of code that uses an [HttpClient and AngleSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1), as the official microsoft documentation, to test a razor page. So I reuse it to grab the cookie from the response.

```
private async Task<string> GetAuthenticationCookie()
{
    var formName = nameof(LoginModel.LoginForm); //this is the bounded model for the login page
    var dto =
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            [$"{formName}.Username"] = "foo",
            [$"{formName}.Password"] = "bar",
        };

    var page = HttpClient.GetAsync("/login").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var content = HtmlHelpers.GetDocumentAsync(page).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    //this is the AndleSharp
    var authResult =
        await HttpClient
            .SendAsync(
                (IHtmlFormElement)content.QuerySelector("form[id='login-form']"),
                (IHtmlButtonElement)content.QuerySelector("form[id='login-form']")
                    .QuerySelector("button"),
                dto);
    _ = authResult.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out var values);
    return values.First();
}
```

Then that value can be reused and passed with the new http request.

```
//in my test, the cookie is a given (from the given-when-then approach) pre-requirement
protected void Given()
{
    var cookie = GetAuthenticationCookie().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    //The http client is a property that comes from the TestServer, when creating a client http for tests as usual. Only this time I set the auth cookie to it
    HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Set-Cookie", cookie);
    var page = await HttpClient.GetAsync($"/admin/protectedPage");
    //this will be a 200 OK because it's an authenticated request with whatever claims and identity the /login page applied
}
```